# Как работает Robocopy?

Tags: windows, администрирование, bat, totalcommander

Почему, например, Total Commander при пропуске файлов, которые были скопированы приступает к копированию спустя длительное кол-во времени, а Robocopy быстро пробегает по каталогам и быстро начинает копирование недостающих файлов?

Comment: возможно потому, что TotalComander делает сравнение не только имен файлов, но и, например размера и других атрибутов, а Robocopy только проверку по именам, но это только предположение

Comment: @rdorn, у меня есть тоже предположение, что robocopy ни заходит в каждую директорию, а делает сравнение по хешу и не перебирает каждый файл. Но это тоже предположение...